Is the miracle in Sarojini's story an allusion?
In chapter 38 of Maryse Condé's L'Évangile du nouveau monde, Pascal, the main character, remembers a story that Sarojini had told him about a strike by untouchables in India (possibly in Jaipur):

Un jour … les intouchables avaient fait grève, car ils n'en pouvaient plus de la modicité de leur salaire. Aussi, les latrines débordaient, les matière fécales s'entassaient dans les pots de chambre, tandit qu'une odeur pestilentielle se répandait à travers toute la ville. Mais ne voilà-t-il pas qu'un matin, en se réveillant, les habitants avaient vu les jardins et les terrasses couverts de roses qui avaient remplacé la laideur par leur éclat inattendu. Ce miracle avait marqué la fin de la grève.

Translation:

One day … the untouchables went on strike because they were fed up with their low wages. As a result, the latrines overflowed, faeces piled up in the chamber pots and a pestilential stench spread through the city. But then, one morning, the inhabitants woke up to find their gardens and terraces covered in roses, which had replaced the ugliness with their unexpected radiance. This miracle marked the end of the strike.

I can't avoid the impression that this miracle is an allusion to some other text but I can't think of what text that might be. (An allusion to Job sitting on a dunghill doesn't seem to work here.) What sort of allusion could be intended here?

A number of Catholic saints turned bread into roses, but that doesn't seem to work here either.
